# Why I getting another connectionState type after connectionState.done in a StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a `StreamController` to handle authentication. I subscribe a user when the sign in is completed. So I create a class for that:

```dart
class AuthAPI {
  final FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final StreamController<User> _authStatusController = StreamController<User>.broadcast();

  Stream<User> get onAuthStatusChanged => _authStatusController.stream;

  // Facebook Sign In
  Future<User> facebookSignIn() async {
    FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['public_profile', 'email']);
    switch(result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        return _sendFacebookUserDataToAPI(result);
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        return null;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print('Cancelled');
        return null;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  // Sign Out
  void signOut() async {
    facebookLogin.logOut();
    _authStatusController.sink.add(null);
    _authStatusController.close();
  }

  Future<User> _sendFacebookUserDataToAPI(FacebookLoginResult result) async {
    final String facebookToken = result.accessToken.token;
    final Response graphResponse = await _dio.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/me?fields='
            'first_name,last_name,email,picture.height(200)&access_token=$facebookToken');
    final profile = jsonDecode(graphResponse.data);

    ApiProvider apiProvider = ApiProvider();

    UserSocialAuth userSocialAuth = UserSocialAuth(
      firstName: profile['first_name'],
      lastName: profile['last_name'],
      email: profile['email'],
      provider: 'facebook',
      providerUserId: profile['id']
    );

    Map socialSignIn = await apiProvider.socialSignIn(userSocialAuth);
    User user;
    if (socialSignIn.containsKey('access_token')) {
      Map userData = await apiProvider.currentUser(socialSignIn['access_token']);
      user = User.fromJson(userData['data']);
      apiProvider.setAccessToken(socialSignIn['access_token']);
      _authStatusController.sink.add(user);
      print("Login Successful");
    } else {
      _authStatusController.sink.addError(socialSignIn['error']);
    }
    _authStatusController.close();
    return user;
  }
}
```

and this is my `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: userBloc.authStatus,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.connectionState);
        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.active:
            User user = snapshot.data;
            if (user == null) {
              return SignInSignUpScreen();
            }
            return _showHomeUI(user, snapshot);
          case ConnectionState.done:
            User user = snapshot.data;
            if (user == null) {
              return SignInSignUpScreen();
            }
            print(user);
            return _showHomeUI(user, snapshot);
          default:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      }
    );
```

So, when I make the login, then it shows a `CircularProgressIndicator`, and if the authentication is successful, then it has to show the home screen. But, it stills showing the login screen, and when I print the output of the `connectionState`, I see that after the `connectionState.done`, the `connectionState` pass to `connectionState.waiting` and I do not know why.

Here is the output of the console:

[image: screenshot console output]

And when it reaches to the last `connectionState.done`, it does not have data.

Comment: hard to follow your workflow when you remove the print() statements from your code.

Comment: @Marc sorry, I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `_authStatusController.close();` in the end of `_sendFacebookUserDataToAPI` method – that means that the underlying stream is finished and you stream listener enters "done" state.

You should instead create e.g. `dispose()` method in `AuthAPI` class and call `_authStatusController.close()` there. This method should be called when `AuthAPI` is no longer needed.